# Data binding to view is too much slow while using web service

Tags: objective-c, json, web-services

I am using web services for iPhone App development. I used NSDictionary  for fetching data using JSONParsing. It's coming fast from web services but it's too much slow while binding to my view/XIB.I am not getting what is the actual issue with this.Because it's working fast on android but not on iPhone.Is their any other solution or example to solve this issue.

Code -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //returning cell with name & logo
    NSLog(@"activity array = %@",activityArray);
    addNameList =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    addThumbnails = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    addActivityId = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int x=0; x<[activityArray count]; x++)
    {
        NSDictionary* toDist = [activityArray objectAtIndex:x];
        [addNameList addObject:[toDist objectForKey:@"activity"]];
        [addThumbnails addObject:[toDist objectForKey:@"icon"]];
        [addActivityId addObject:[toDist objectForKey:@"id"]];
    }

    activityList = addNameList;
    thumbnails = addThumbnails;
    activityIdList = addActivityId;
 }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [activityList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIImageView *backImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,277,58)];
    backImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    backImage.opaque = NO;
    backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackgroundImage.png"];
    cell.backgroundView = backImage;
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Your question is not remotely connected to xcode. It just happens to be the ide that you are using.

Comment: Please show some code, especially where you bind the data to the view. And put some details on how you found out that the request is slow but the data binding is not.

Comment: Make sure you are updating your UI on the main thread. It is possible that your download happens on a background thread which you are then updating your view with (which you should not be doing). It will appear that your UI updates slowly because of this. As @HermannKlecker says, post some code.

Comment: Where is the code?...

Comment: @Hermann Klecker Please see my edited code..And i found the actual issue...It's taking too much time while loading images..Please see in "CellForRowAtIndexPath" where i wrote i code for every cell and which is taking time to load images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you haven't figured out how to load the image data in the background

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    });
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your comment can you explain?

Comment: That still makes no sense? I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Have a look at this code example from Apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I download above code but not able to find out the solution..I tried "[cell setNeedsLayout]" but still images are not on their proper place..when scrolling it is automatically changing images in all cells..Is their any solution for this..

Comment: I think what is happening is you are downloading the image but by the time it is finished downloading the image required for that cell has changed to a new one hence the images appearing in the wrong place, if you don't scroll the table view it should be right. You need to check if the image downloaded is the correct one. You should also be caching the data so the user doesn't have to keep download the same user. http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-tutorial-image-cache-and-loading-thumbnails-using-mknetworkkit/

Comment: thank you very much..my problem is solved with simple 1 line of code.. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I am not getting what is the actual issue with this.

Neither are we, frankly. It's impossible to tell why your code is slow if you don't show it to us. Sounds like the real problem is that you're not sure which part of your code is slow. So let me tell you how to figure that out: **profile your code**.

Xcode includes a powerful tool called Instruments that lets you look at how much time your app is spending in each method, how much memory it's using, how much power, and so on. Explaining how to use it is a little too in-depth for this response, so please start with the [*Instruments User Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) The short version is that you can use the Product->Test menu command to launch your app under Instruments, and doing so will let you collect and analyze a number of different kinds of performance data. If you find a high-level method that seems to be taking longer than it should, you can drill down into the method and look at the methods that it calls, and the methods that those methods call in turn.

Armed with the information that you can get from Instruments, you won't have to wonder about why your code is slow -- you'll be able to find the answer empirically.